# Local homeomorphism restricted to an open set is a local homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a local homeomorphism, i.e. for every $x\in X$ there exists an open set $U$ of $X$ such that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$ and $f|_{U}:U\rightarrow f(U)$ is an homeomorphism. Then if $V$ is an open subset of $X$ then again $f|_{V}$ is a local homeomorphism.

My attempt:
Let $x\in V$, by hypothesysi there exists some open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $x\in U$, $f(U)$ open in $Y$ and $f|_{U}$ an homeomorphism. Define $W:=U\cap V$ and is clear that $x\in W$, $W$ is open in $U$ and we need to check that $f|_{U}(W)$ is open in $f(U)$. This is really the step where I am stuck because I think that $f|_{U}(W)=f|_{V}(W)=f|_{V}(U)\cap f(V)$ but I don't feel that $f|_{V}(U)$ really have sense because $U$ is not a subset of $V$ so how can I apply $f|_{V}$ to $U$?

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: $f|_U$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, and $W$ is an open subset of $U$ (why?), so it follows that $f(W)=f|_U(W)$ is an open subset of $f(U)$. since $f(U)$ is an open subset of $Y$, $f(W)$ is in turn an open subset of $Y$ (why?)